# Rails/Devise. Include captcha response param within sign_in process

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, captcha

Without making a custom Sessions controller that inherits from the hidden devise controller, I want to figure out a way of adding the parameter, "g-recaptcha-response" to be included in the authenticating process from the default devise view.

Here's my view with the recaptcha figure included. When I click on it I do get a response when my app calls the SessionController#create method. I'm trying to figure out how to make this process detect that the captcha form has been clicked and authenticates the user logging in because of it.

```
<h2>Log in</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "email" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>

  <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.check_box :remember_me %>
      <%= f.label :remember_me %>
    </div>
  <% end -%>

  <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LeeL5gUAAAAADbq0vt4d9biAs8oegkPx9ttUkKb"></div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Log in" %>
  </div>

<% end %>
<%= link_to 'Sign Up', new_user_registration_path %>
```

In essence, if a bot were to attempt automatically signing in repeatedly, the devise controller would see that the captcha was not clicked and stops them from trying to log in.

Comment: Hi! Do you use a custom registration controller for Devise? If yes, could you add t the code to your question?

Comment: Check this https://github.com/igorkasyanchuk/new_google_recaptcha for google captcha, it doesn't require to click captcha

Comment: Well, I do have a custom registration controller, but logging in with devise has to do with the sessions controller.

I was taking a look at the new google recaptcha and it seems pretty cool. How would I coordinate the captcha form with the Sessions#create method?

Comment: Igor, is this gem capable of using a captcha was clicked or used when I login through devise as your documentation shows that it only works with devise if I'm creating a new user?